# How to solve this CORS error where I am trying to push files to IPFS using infura

Tags: cors, http-headers, blockchain, ipfs, ipfs-http-client

I am getting these two cors errors:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/add?stream-channels=true&progress=false. (Reason: CORS request external redirect not allowed).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0/add?stream-channels=true&progress=false. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

How should I solve this? Kindly help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.